# Making changes according to the results of a search

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a database full of businesses infos. It goes from Attorneys to Fast Food restaurants!
The guy who implemented the data all put the different business in the same category.

I'd like to change the category of the business according to the search results. For example: I search for business that have "attorney" in the name column, and change the category_ID from 35 to 15.

**From:**

```
NAME          | category_ID|
----------------------------
Attorney 1     |      35
Attorney 2     |      35
restaurant     |      35
```

**TO**

```
NAME           | category_ID|
-----------------------------
Attorney 1     |      18
Attorney 2     |      18
Restaurant     |      35
```

I'm new to MySql and I'm still looking for the magic formula to do this.

Any idea anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no magic formula .. what is `18` and `35`?

Answer (score 0):

try this
`update tablename

set category_d = 18

where lower(name) like 'attorney%'`

This will make the category id as 18 (as per your example) where name contains Attorney.  I have used lower just to make it case insensitive. You may avoid and just write `name = 'Attorney%'`